# How to get value of the selected item from the itemlist

Tags: android, listview

I m not getting the value of the selected item from the list view and i am getting the value but "com.contantbean........." . I want to get name and phone no. from the list view which is selected.

```
private ListView listView;
private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.existingcontact);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
        objContact.setName(name);
        objContact.setPhoneNo(phoneNumber);
        list.add(objContact);

    }
    phones.close();

    ContanctAdapter objAdapter = new ContanctAdapter(
            ExistingContact.this, R.layout.cdesign, list);
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    String str = list.get(position).toString();

        ContactBean bean = (ContactBean) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
       Toast.makeText(ExistingContact.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //registerForContextMenu(listView);

}
```

Comment: get the item from the list you use to adapt the listview with. say list.get(position) and you will get the item at that position. if using a cursor, then in that case, move cursor to that position and work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the `List` from where you populated the `Spinner`. If so, you can access the selected value by.-

```
itemsList.get(position);
```

Comment: List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();